Maven artifact version conflict
My project is relying on an artifact of a new version, and another dependency of my project is relying on the same artifact of an old version. The new version is not compatible with the old version. So my app boot failed. I hope I could use the new version in my source and keep my dependency use the old version during run time. Is it possible? I am running a Springboot application.
ChatGPT prompt me to use maven shading plugin. But it seems not working. I can still see only the new version jar package in the built jar.

Maven implicitly assumes that all newer versions of a library can replace an older one. This assumption does not hold in modern times. You can do what you suggest but it is not a good idea - much better to lift your code to work with the new version or stay on the old.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please show the pom file... which artifact we are talking about and also which different versions are used?

I totally agree that I should modify the code to use a consistent version. But the fact is, I don't own the source of some artifacts. So it is not always feasible. Anyway, I found maven-shade-plugin could resolve the problem. I list it as an answer.
